# How to import mysqli connection from the include file?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is there any idea how to import mysqli connection from the include file?

db_connect.php

```
<?php
class DB_CONNECT {
    /* -- */
    function connect() {
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';
        $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
        $db = mysqli_select_db($con, DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_connect_error()) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
        return $con;
    }
    /* -- */
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
$response = array();
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT *FROM tasks");
```

If I do this, will get this error message.

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in index.php on line XXX

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump($db);`?

Comment: You don't need `mysqli_select_db()`. You can do `mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE)` with constant from your config file.

Comment: The proper answer to this question would explain that you don't need the class you have created. You should also enable MySQLi exceptions, because your current code is leaking sensitive information. If you want to use OOP then you should use it for MySQLi too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the ***function*** of that *class* instead of using the *object* of it, As the connection you intend to create can be done by returned $**con** variable in that function and not the *object* itself.

`$conn= $db->connect();`

`$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *FROM tasks");`

**EDIT** : Creating $conn in query statement is not a good thing as mentioned by @YourCommonSense and @dharman

Comment: @YourCommonSense How's that ? Do you mean we need to call the function seperately ?

Comment: It's pretty much pointless to create a connection for one use only. It is also useless to have that function in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Given DB_CONNECT class doesn't really add any value, just get rid of it, and simply put a proper connection code into db_connect.php, and then just include this file in your scripts. Mysqli is a class already, no need to add another one without any added value. You can create a $db variable out of mysqli class as well.

First, write a [proper mysqli connection code](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect) (my article dedicated to the matter, I highly recommend to read it as it explains many things that are wrong or missing in your current code):

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
    $db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
    $db->set_charset($charset);
} catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
     throw new \mysqli_sql_exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
}
```

And then *just include* this file in other scripts: a `$db` variable would be already there:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
$response = $db->query("SELECT *FROM tasks")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

see - just two lines!

Answer (score 2):

`$db = new DB_CONNECT();` invokes the object.

You need to call:

```
$con= $db->connect();
```

And then use `$con` as:

```
  $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *FROM tasks");
```